# ExitAnimation between composable within NavHost

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Im playing with `AnimatedVisibility` in jetpack compose and find out that the exit animation doesnt work because the composable destroyed(?) before the animation started. I tested it with delay enabled to see if the animation worked if the destroy got delayed, and it works. But it doesnt look good and seems forced, beside it doesnt work with default onBackPressed. Here is my code:

```
NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = startDestination) {
    composable() { // First Screen }
    composable(
        ...
    ) { navBackStackEntry ->

        val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()

        AnimatedVisibility(
            visibleState = remember { MutableTransitionState(!detailScreenIsVisible) }
                .apply { targetState = detailScreenIsVisible },
            enter = slideInHorizontally(
                initialOffsetX = { it / 4 }
            ),
            exit = slideOutHorizontally(
                targetOffsetX = { it / 4 }
            ),
        ) {
            DetailScreen(
                ...
                onNavigateUp = {
                    detailScreenIsVisible = false
                    scope.launch {
                        delay(10L)
                        navController.navigateUp()
                    }
                }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

What is the workaround for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check this link to [Navigating with Compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#nav-to-composable) from the Google Docs it states that:

> The anim block cannot be used with Navigation Compose. Transition Animations in Navigation Compose is being tracked in this feature request.

Therefore, Google is working on it, but it is not available yet. You can keep track of the status of this feature [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/172112072) (I'm checking from time to time) and wait for the animations to be widely available. In the meantime, I found a quite [interesting article](https://proandroiddev.com/navigation-with-animated-transitions-using-jetpack-compose-daeb00d4fb45) written by Johann Blake that implements it's own navigation framework. He also made it to be able to pass any object between navigation screens, which avoids the bundle limitations that we were dealing with in the Navigation Component.

Comment: Update: As per the issue tracking status, it looks like the issue is solved by using Google's [Accompanist Library](https://github.com/google/accompanist), with plans to move all functionality to Compose v1.1.0 when it is released (currently, 1.1.0-rc01)